# How to make resource policy to limit the access to custom domain for lambda API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the API Gateway and lambda.

API Gateway domain is like this below.

https://xxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/

then , I set custom domain for lambda URL such as

https://xxxxxx.example.com

However even after set this custom domain, access to https://xxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/ is available.

I want to limit the access Gateway domain from only `https://xxxxxx.example.com`

I research around and found I should use Resource Policy.

However how can I set the resource policy for API Gateway to limit the access??

Honestly saying I have never write the resource policy from the scratch.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the execute-api endpoint by simply going into the `Settings` for your API gateway and disabling the `Default Endpoint` configuration:

[image]

Or you can disable it using the following command (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-disable-default-endpoint.html)):

```
aws apigatewayv2 update-api \
    --api-id abcdef123 \
    --disable-execute-api-endpoint
```

**Important**:

After you disable your execute-api endpoint, you will have to redeploy your API:

[image]

Comment: Thank you !! it perfectly hits the spot!!! I don't need to make `ResorcePolicy`.